# How to get an object value, which property is equal to a variable value

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Please help me to solve the task below.

I want to display an object value, which property is equal to the variable txt. If `txt = "my location"`, I want to display the value of “my location”.

And also I want to display it in such way:

city: value1,

street: value2

```
var obj = {“my name”: “first second”, “my location”: {“city”: “value1”, “street”: “value2”}};
objkeys = Object.keys(obj);
for (var i = 0; i < objkeys.length; ++i) console.log(objkeys[i]);
var txt = “my location”;
if (txt === objkeys[i]) console.log(???)
```

What should be written instesd of ???

Thanks!

Comment: No need of iterating over keys, use `obj[txt]` directly.

Comment: your expected result

Comment: The last line is not using the for loop; you should add { ... }

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically access object property using variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable)

Comment: Thank you! Yes, it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var obj = {"my name": "first second", "my location": {"city": "value1", "street": "value2"}};
var txt = "my location"

console.log(obj[txt])
// {"city": "value1", "street": "value2"}
```

Comment: What does this code do? Does it solve the problem? If yes, how? If not, why?

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj = {"my name": "first second", "my location": {"city": "value1", "street": "value2"}};
var text="my location"
for (var key in obj[text]){
    console.log(key+':'+obj[text][key])
}
```

use obj[text] to get the value of "my location" in obj, here you will get an object. Then for each key of this obj, you can get the 'key' directly and use that key to get the value of each key in "my location" by obj[text][key]

Comment: @Sawyer please edit your post and move explanation from comment to answer